# What is the proof of infinite number of parallel lines in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I know that parallel axiom in Hyperbolic geometry is that there at least two parallel lines to line $a$ through a given point $A$. But as I know it can be proven that there are infinitely many of them, what is the proof ?

Comment: I swear the proof is given under one of Euclid's propositions... but I can't seem to remember it myself!

Comment: What are your other axioms?

Comment: @user477343 By Euclid's propositions you mean one of his theorems in neutral geometry ?

Comment: Euclid's fifth postulate says exactly not this.

Comment: @SteveKangas I'm talking about Hyperbolic geometry which is non-euclidean.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Let it be Hilbert's axioms with the parallel axiom of Hyperbolic geometry instead of Euclid's

Comment: @Юрій Ярош I was responding to user477343, who was, maybe joking?

Comment: @SteveKangas Oh, sorry.

Comment: You can literally see the infinitely many parallel lines in the Poincare disk model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#/media/File:Poincare_disc_hyperbolic_parallel_lines.svg

Comment: Once you know it's true for one point, you can move all the parallel lines to any other point using isometries.  But probably you're looking for a proof derived from axioms.

Comment: @SteveKangas I know that I can see infinitely many of them in models of Hyperbolic geometry, but I was interested in a proof. Does this proof at least exists ?

Comment: It's possible to prove this given a particular set of axioms. Like Hilbert's.

Comment: @SteveKangas sorry I got confused, hahah.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the two lines through $A$, that converge on the two ends of $a$.

A point $B$ that lies between these convergent lines, will create a line $AB$, that crosses the two convergent lines at $A$, and so will always be opposite one of the convergent lines to $a$.  Thus it never crosses $a$.

Comment: I don't know this terminology, so sorry for the additional questions, but what convergent line means in hyperbolic geometry ?

Comment: When they say there are two parallels, these are the ones that meet at infinity, such at the edge of a Poincare disk.  These two cross at A, and make an X-shape.  If the line a is at the bottom of the X, and B is placed in the left or right side of the X, the line AB will pass from the left-side into the right side.

Comment: The underlying idea here is that the hyperbolic plane is still orientable, and the line $AB$ can not cross $a$ because it's above the two lines that meet at infinity.

Comment: How you can prove that line AB won't go out the X shape ?

Comment: Suppose the line $a$ has the ends at $L$ and $R$.  Then the lines through $A$ run $AL$ and $AR$.  If $B$ is in the X-shape, on the right hand side, a line to the left of $AB$ crosses $BR$, $BA$, $BL$ and $a$ in that order, because $AB$ crosses $BL$ at $B$ only.  On the right hand side, the order is $BL$, $BA$, $BR$ and $a$, meaning that $BA$ never crosses $BR$ and thus can not approach $a$.  Therefore $AB$ never crosses $a$.

Comment: Sorry but what is the "end of a line" ? Line doesn't have ends as far as I know.